# OOP - Child class call parent class' method without losing its context

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have a class B that inherits from class A. Class A defines a method, for example, toArray() that will loop through the properties and return an array with them.

I want to call $b->toArray() and get an array of the properties of B and not A (though the method is defined in A).

Something like this:

```
class A{
    public function toArray(){
        return get_object_vars($this); //$this WHAT is $this?! I want it to be different depending on the which class is instantiated.
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public $my_var = 'Some value';
}

$b = new B;
$b->toArray(); //should contain my_var
```

This code above fails. It will return nothing because A has no properties. How can I achieve this with OOP (in PHP more precisely, but a general explanation would be nice if there is one).

Comment: [Except that it does](https://3v4l.org/Ar8RE) (unless your child var is declared private)..... though you're discarding the returned value without doing anything with it

Comment: excellent! but since $this is the child class, I thought the properties would be visible in that context

Comment: No, $this is the instance of the child class, but the method is running in the inheritance context of the parent, and property visibility applies, so private is not visible outside of the inheritance context in which it is running

Answer (score 1):

Well the approach itself is correct, but the problem is, you don't have a function `toArray()` in Class A.

you have to rename your function `foo()` to `toArray()`.

Try this instead:

```
class A {

    public function toArray() {
        return get_object_vars( $this ); //$this WHAT is $this?! I want it to be different depending on the which class is instantiated.
    }

}

class B extends A {

    public $my_var = 'Some value';

}

$b = new B;
var_dump( $b->toArray() ); //should contain my_var
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["my_var"]=>
  string(10) "Some value"
}
```

Comment: now I do, and I still get nothing as result. toArray is my function in real world so I got confused when I wrote it here. Of course this is just a piece of my actual classes

Comment: I've added the output to my answer, as you can see in this case it works, so I guess the problem you have is another one. Did you take a look at you error_log?

Comment: @VictorFerreira It could be as simple that he didn't use an output construct like `var_dump`.  This code works for me.